# On what factors JVM dependent on Operating system

Tags: java, c, jvm

We know that Java is platform independent but JVM is platform dependent. Byte Code is converted into machine code by Java Interpreter. I want to know on which factors jvm is dependent on uderlying operating system. 
I also want to know what C language does to source code that the compiled code can not run in another operating system .

Comment: tl;tr: C compiler translates code to machine code. The machine code to which it translates the code depends on where and how you compile the code. The JVM is compiled in the same way, but its job is to run java bytecode. Depending on which system you run, you install a different JVM, the JVM's differ, but they all know how to handle the same input

Comment: I understand this but I want to know on which factors jvm is dependent on operating system.

Comment: @user172069 Can you rephrase that last comment? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: When you type on the command line 'java mypackage.MyClass' you actually call the java executable which is java.exe from say %PROGRAMFILES%/jdk/bin in windows or the java executable from /somepath/jdk/bin in linux. Java.exe cannot run on linux, the linux executable cannot run on windows either. Both will call system dependent libs that are not compatible because they make calls to OS specific APIs (for file handling, graphics....)

Comment: Reading the disk, writing the disk, drawing to screen, reading from the keyboard, reading the mouse movement, printing, etc.

Comment: @Duncan-Depedning on which operating you run, you install a different JVM. Why for every operating system, there is  need to install different JVM, so on which factors it depends on?

Comment: @user172069 Because each OS has its own way of doing things. You don't open a network socket on Windows in the same way as you do in Linux. So you need different JVMs to interpret the same Java command.